# Why retryWhen() doesn't hold?

Tags: java, rx-java

Suppose I have the following code:

```
Observable.error(new Throwable()).
    retryWhen(notificationHandler -> Observable.never()).
    subscribe(x -> {}, t -> log("error"), () -> log("completed"));
```

I expect, that it will hold execution, because `retryWhen` will never resubscribe to or done.

But when I run it, application stops, even not indicating error or competed.

Why does it not hold ever?

P.S. I had idea, that execution break because it all run on single thread. And tried move retryWhen() handler to another thread:

```
Observable.error(new Throwable()).
        retryWhen(notificationHandler -> Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            log("never");
        }).observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())).
        subscribe(x -> {}, t -> log("err"), () -> log("completed"));
```

But it does'not help - still prints 'never' and stops.

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to do? What kind of behaviour do you want to implement? What kind of application do you have? Is it an Android application?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the explaniation from Dan at following link: http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/

It does say

> Let's look at the last part first. The emissions of the Observable returned determines whether or not resubscription happens. If it emits onCompleted or onError then it doesn't resubscribe. But if it emits onNext then it does (regardless of what's actually in the onNext).

retryWhen subscribes to Observable.never() which in turn does not provide any value. Therefore the pipeline is at a stall and your application will not continoue. You either throw e onError/ onComplete or just a value:

Lets have a look at this test. It shows that no value will be emitted and it will not be resubscribed.

```
@Test
void name2() throws Exception {
    boolean await = Observable.error(new Throwable())
            .doOnEach(objectNotification -> System.out.println("x"))
            .retryWhen(notificationHandler -> Observable.never())
            .map(o -> -42)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .test()
            .await(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    assertThat(await).isFalse();
}
```

> I expect, that it will hold execution, because retryWhen will never resubscribe to or done. But when I run it, application stops, even not indicating error or competed.

The application does not indicate anything, because subscribe onComplete/ onError is never reached, because of Observable.never().

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you are confused with `Observable.never` and `Observable.empty`. As you use `Observable.never`, it will not retry neither completed(The error has been consumed by `notificationHandler`).

Second, when you use `retryWhen`, you should subscribe on the given `notificationHandler`. Or it will retry immediately when subscribe(The parameter `Func1<> notificationHandler`will be called when subscribe on it, and retry when the return Observable emit item).